# R seasonal decomposition

Tags: r, time-series

I simulate a time series with periodic and linear components and try to use the R stl function to analyze it

```
n = 1000
x = ts(0.1*rnorm(n) + sin(6*pi*(1:n)/n) + (1:n)/n,frequency=n)
plot(x)
stl(x,"per")
```

but get a message

```
Error in stl(x, "per") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

How do I use stl on the simulated time series?

Comment: Your `ts` command explicitly assigns all `n` data to a single time period--there's not much to be done with that!

Comment: Try setting 'n' to something c/w the implicit underlying cycle period implied by `6*pi`, .... perhaps 12 or 24?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be more than 2 periods, so frequency must be less than `n/2`

```
n = 1000
x = ts(0.1*rnorm(n) + sin(6*pi*(1:n)/n) + (1:n)/n,
       frequency=n/2.1)

plot(x)
stl(x,"per")
```